# Python: memory allocation problem for solve_ivp

Tags: python-3.x, out-of-memory, ode

I am experiencing a problem that seems to be related to memory allocation when using the ODE solver solve_ivp.

While the scaling (execution time with grid points) seems to give the expected linear result (once I use the sparsity of the Jacobian matrix), everything breaks when I have arrays with a little more than 10 million elements. It shouldn't be like that, since in principle they should require less than 0.5GB of RAM and I have 32GB...

Here is a minimal example that solves the simple equation `y'=1` and yet reproduces the problem. In particular, it runs well up to 10^7 points and breaks with a little more. It takes ~O(100) seconds to execute on my system.

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import time
from time import perf_counter
from scipy.sparse import dia_array


def time_integration( Num ):

    t_grid = np.linspace( start=0., stop=1., num=Num )
    data = [np.zeros( Num, dtype=np.float64 )]
    jac_sparsity = dia_array( (data, [0]), shape=(Num, Num), dtype=np.float64 )

    def fun_rhs( t, y ):
        dfdt = np.ones( len(t_grid) )
        return dfdt

    start_time = perf_counter()
    output = scipy.integrate.solve_ivp( fun_rhs, [ min(t_grid), max(t_grid) ], np.zeros( len(t_grid) ), 
                                   method='BDF', 
                                   t_eval=None, 
                                   jac_sparsity=jac_sparsity, 
                                   dense_output=False, 
                                   events=None,
                                   vectorized=False,
                                   args=None, atol=1.e-2, rtol=1.e-2 )
    stop_time = perf_counter()
    return stop_time - start_time


start_log = 1.
stop_log = 7.2   ## !!!!! if 6. (or even 7.) it works fine !!!!!
timeSteps_array = np.logspace(start=start_log, stop=stop_log, num=int( stop_log-start_log ) + 1, dtype=int)
print(f'array of time steps (len = {len(timeSteps_array)}): {timeSteps_array}')
print('')


start_time_script = perf_counter()
runtime_array = np.zeros( len(timeSteps_array) )
runtime_array = [time_integration( it ) for it in timeSteps_array]
stop_time_script = perf_counter()


print(f'runtime for each Nt = {runtime_array} sec')
print(f'the script took {stop_time_script - start_time_script} seconds to run.')
plt.loglog(timeSteps_array, runtime_array, lw=2., color='blue', label='num test')
plt.loglog(timeSteps_array, time_integration( timeSteps_array[1] ) * timeSteps_array/timeSteps_array[1], lw=1.5, ls='--', color='red', label='linear')
plt.xlabel('Total number of points', fontsize=13)
plt.ylabel('Time [sec]', fontsize=13)
plt.legend(frameon=False, fontsize=12)
plt.savefig('TimeScaling.pdf',format='pdf',bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
plt.show()
```

It should be useful to add that the error I get is:

```
RuntimeError: SUPERLU_MALLOC fails for buf in intCalloc() at line 159 in file /private/tmp/scipy-20230221-70667-mabqq4/scipy-1.10.1/scipy/sparse/linalg/_dsolve/SuperLU/SRC/memory.c
```

Comment: What is the length in time direction of the numerical solution, that is `len(output.y[0])`, in the mock-up and in your application?

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, it should be the length of the grid that you set at the beginning too.

Comment: Not necessarily. Your integration here is of a constant. The step size controller should drive the step size rapidly up, as every method will give the correct linear function as interpolation polynomial. But as your Jacobian is wrong, this might not be true for the code above. // The general idea is that you estimated the data size for the stepper, which is linear in `Num`. However, the largest object in memory will be the output which in general is quadratic. So for `Num = 1e7` you get `8e7` bytes for the state vectors, about `1e9` for the stepper data and about `1e15` for the output.

Comment: Hi! So I checked, in the code above len(output.y) is in fact equal to the number of grid points (Num) that I am using, while len(output.y[0]) = 10 for each Num. However, I am relatively new to this, so I would need you to expand your comment a little bit, to understand. 1) Why is my Jacobian wrong (and how should I fix it)? 2) Why is the output quadratic in Num (the time scaling is perfectly linear, I don't understand...)? 3) What do you mean by "estimate the data size for the stepper"? Thanks a lot and sorry for the maybe naive questions.

Comment: In the text above I added the error that I get with Num = 10^(7.2) points.

Comment: So the solver was progressing in the most efficient way. You are solving `y'=f(t,y)=1` in `Num` instances. The Jacobian of that system is `f_y(t,y)=0`, here the zero matrix of the system dimension. As said, the solution is `y(t)=y(0)+t`, which will be reproduced be every solver independent of the step size. If you switch over to a less trivial system, the step size will be more restricted, giving more time nodes in the solution. As the time interval is [0, Num] the number of time nodes will most likely become proportional to Num, thus the quadratic size of `output.y`.

Comment: Ok sure but then I shouldn't have this memory allocation problem for the simple problem stated above, `y' = 1`. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Just to clarify again, the code I posted in the question is a minimal example (certainly simple) that reproduces a problem that I have in a much more complicated equation. I would like to understand why I get this memory allocation problem in this simple example.